# Intersection and difference function on sets using BST in haskell

Tags: haskell, set

I have implement the Set datatype using Binary search tree.

My implementation is as follows:-

```
data Set a = Empty | Node a (Set a) (Set a)
```

I have also written some other functions such as toList, fromList, and Insert. (took help in my previous question)

These are the functions that I have written until now:

```
insert :: Ord a => a -> Set a -> Set a
insert x Empty = Node x Empty Empty
insert x (Node e l r)
| x == e = Node e l r
| x < e = Node e (insert x l) r
| otherwise = Node e l (insert x r) 

fromList :: Ord a => [a] -> Set a
fromList [] = Empty
fromList (x:xs) = insert x (fromList xs)

toList :: Set a -> [a]
toList Empty = [] 
toList (Node val l r) = toList l ++ val : (toList r)
```

I have been trying to solve the following functions for quite a long time now. Can you please help me out. I have made multiple attempts , but none of them work.

```
   ---- return the common elements between two Sets
  intersection :: (Ord a) => Set a -> Set a -> Set a   

  -- all the elements in Set A *not* in Set B,
  -- {1,2,3,4} `difference` {3,4} => {1,2}
  -- {} `difference` {0} => {}
  difference :: (Ord a) => Set a -> Set a -> Set a
```

Here's my attempt to this function, which compiles without an error , but it does not solve the problem:

```
intersection :: (Ord a) => Set a -> Set a -> Set a
intersection Empty Empty = Empty
intersection l Empty = Empty
intersection Empty r = Empty 
intersection (Node val1 Empty Empty) (Node val2 Empty Empty) = if val1 
== val2 then (Node val1 Empty Empty) else Empty
intersection l (Node val1 l1 r1) =  Node val1 (intersection l l1) r1
```

I cannot import any external module/ libraries. I have also written a setmap function if that helps .

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "I have also written ... toList, fromList,". Ok so to dip your toe in the water, `toList` both the set arguments; scan the lists; as you 'consume' an element and pass to output (or not), step down one (or both) of the lists.

Comment: all these tasks are variations on the old [`samefringe` problem](http://www.dreamsongs.com/10ideas.html) -- the simultaneous enumeration of the two tree's fringes is called for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, it's not the best in performance but work, solution is create a list and use element function inside filter function.

```haskell
module Lib
  (
    insert, fromList, toList, element, intersection, difference

  )
where
data Set a = Empty | Node a (Set a) (Set a) deriving Show

insert :: Ord a => a -> Set a -> Set a
insert x Empty = Node x Empty Empty
insert x (Node e l r)
  | x == e = Node e l r
  | x < e = Node e (insert x l) r
  | otherwise = Node e l (insert x r)

fromList :: Ord a => [a] -> Set a
fromList = foldr insert Empty

toList :: Set a -> [a]
toList Empty = []
toList (Node val l r) = toList l ++ val : toList r

element :: Ord t => Set t -> t -> Bool
element Empty _ = False
element (Node v l r) x
  | x == v = True
  | x < v = element l x
  | otherwise  = element r x

intersection :: (Ord a) => Set a -> Set a -> Set a
intersection s1 s2 = intersect
  where
    ls2 = toList s2
    intersect = fromList $ filter (element s1) ls2

difference :: (Ord a) => Set a -> Set a -> Set a
difference s1 s2 = diff
  where
    ls1 = toList s1
    diff = fromList $ filter (not.element s2) ls1
```

Comment: If you want to dip your toe in a bit further, write a function `split :: Ord a => Set a -> (Set a, Maybe a, Set a)` that splits a set around an element that may or may not be present. How can you use that to implement `union`, `intersection`, and `difference`? If you were to "upgrade" these trees to balanced search trees, this approach would lead to guaranteed-efficient operations.

Comment: @dfeuer interesting,  Could you share a document about that ?

Comment: Look up "Just Join for Parallel Ordered Sets" by Blelloch et al. We use those algorithms in `Data.Map` and `Data.Set` these days. We used to use more complicated but poorly understood and probably actually slower ones by Adams.

Comment: When Adams came up with trees of bounded balance, he saw that there was a simple divide and conquer algorithm scheme for union, and I think also intersection and difference, using something like `split`. Unfortunately, he didn't know a tight bound for its performance. He attempted to optimize unions with a rather complicated "hedge union" algorithm, for which he had no performance bound. Blelloch et al did some very fancy math and proved tight (and optimal) performance bounds for the simple algorithms. There's no obvious reason to believe that the hedge algorithms are similarly good.